# Div with image and text stling

Tags: html, css

I have a div box that contains an image, a header and some text. It's supposed to have the image in the top left corner, h1 in the top-middle between image and div edge, and some rows of text aligned with a margin consistent with the images width, and below the h1

```
<div id="info">
<img src="images/trains.jpg"/>
<h1>News</h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
</div>

#info {
background-color: rgba(255,6,10,1.00);
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
border-right: solid 1px rgba(151,151,151,1.00);
}
```

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Float the image and add margins as appropriate...is one way.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aT9yj/1/)

**CSS**

```
#info {
background-color: rgba(255,6,10,1.00);
width: 500px;
border-right: solid 1px rgba(151,151,151,1.00);
}

#info h1{
    text-align: center;
}

#info img {
    float:left;
    display: block;
    padding:5px;
}

p {
    margin-left:160px;
}
```